# What rotates the eye for rigs (human)?

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

The regular eye controllers just moves the eyes out of their sockets when parented to the eye bones or terribly distorts it when parented to the rig. I have no access to reference rigs due to Sketchfab not working in blender 3.0.

Comment: Although I've never used it, Sketchfab now works in Blender 3.0 according to [this blog](https://sketchfab.com/blogs/community/sketchfab-now-supports-blender-3-0/) from 4 days ago..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified "Eye rig" showing the parts of an armature that are typically used for basic eye control:

[image: Basic Eye rig]

- The `head` bone is the parent of the two `DEF` bones and the `CTRL` bone.
- Each eye has its related `DEF` bone as a bone parent.  The are the only deforming bones in the rig (and thus, they "DEF" prefix.)
- Each `DEF` bone has a *Damped Track* Bone Constraint that uses the `CTRL` bone as a target:

[image: Bone constraint to use the control bone as a damped track target.]

When the `head` bone is moved or rotated, the eyes move with it, because of the parenting.

The `CTRL` bone is used to control the direction that the eyes are looking. It moves them as a pair.

Because the configuration locks the degree that they eyes appear crossed eyed, another pair of bones is often used as *mechanism* bones.  The mechanism bones are laid on top of the `Def` bones and made slightly smaller.

In this case the DEF bones are parented to the mechanism bones and can be used to adjust the degree of cross eyed look, or to individually point the eyes, and the mechanism bones have the tracking constraints.  It is usual to give the prefix `MCH` to mechanism bones.  Here is a close up of the left eye showing a mechanism bone in place.

[image: Mechanism bone overlaid on deformation bone]

Here is a very basic eye rig example blend file:

[image]

Comment: It turns out the tails of the eye bones are at the opposite ends of the head bones of the eyes. I'll make sure to use a reference model in the future.